# How to free an array of char-pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, free

I use this Method to convert values from a list into an array for use in an execvp()-Systemcall:

```
char **list2argarray(struct shellvalue *values, int count)
{
    char **array = (char **)malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    int i = 0;

    while (values)
    {
        char *word = values->word;

        array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(word) + 1);
        strcpy(array[i], word);
        values = values->next;
        i++;
    }
    array[i] = NULL;
    return array;
}
```

What is a proper way to free such Arrays? I tried it with things like

```
void freeargpointer(char **array, int count)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (*array)
    {
        free(*array);
        (*array)++;
    }
}
```

But everytime when i reach the free-syscall, while debugging, the programm crashes with errors like this one:

> free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000060c180 ****

Comment: In `list2argarray()` the program is allocating memory for `count` elements, but running the loop till `values` is non-NULL --- this might be a source of inconsistency and bug.

Comment: You might want `while ( values && (i < count) )` just to avoid `i` going out of range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `(*array)++` doesn't give you the next pointer you allocated, so you can't free it. Your free routine should be:

```
void freeargpointer(char** array)
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; array[i]; i++ )
        free( array[i] );

    free( array );
}
```

Or, similarly,

```
void freeargpointer(char** array)
{
    char **a;

    for ( a = array; *a; a++ )
        free( *a );

    free( array );
}
```

*NOTE:* I removed the `count` argument since it is unnecessary.

Comment: So where is `count` used?

Comment: @MattSom it's not. I carried it along unwittingly from the OP's original code. I'll remove it for clarity.

Comment: Could add about incorrect `array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(word) + 1);`.  Likely needs `array[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(word) + 1);`

Answer (score 4):

This line is wrong.

```
(*array)++;
```

You need to have.

```
++array;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it works, maybe it helps you.

```
 void freeargpointer(char **array, int count)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i)
    free(++array[i]);
}
```

Edit: I'm sorry to forget count it. Normally code is above.

Comment: Where is `count` used?