# Free memory from array of char pointers

Tags: c

I have written a program which takes up to 100 words and stores them in an array. It then works out the average length of the words and prints the result to stderr (among some other basic computation). I am trying to deallocate the memory at the end of the program but am getting this error, not sure why this is an invalid pointer?

Code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *emalloc(size_t s) {
    void *result = malloc(s);
    if (NULL == result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return result;
}

/* n is the size of the array */
void print_array(char **a, int n, double average) {
    if (n == 0) {
        /* do nothing */
    } else {
        if (strlen(a[0]) > average) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", a[0]);
        }
        print_array(a + 1, n - 1, average);
    }
}

int main()
{
    #define SIZE 100
    char *username[SIZE];
    char word[80];
    int num_words = 0;
    double average = 0.0;
    int p;

    /* Read words into array */
    while(num_words < SIZE && 1 == scanf("%s", word)) {
        size_t len = strlen (word);
        username[num_words] = emalloc (len + 1);
        strcpy(username[num_words], word);
        num_words++;
        average += len;
    }

    average = average / num_words;

    print_array(username, num_words, average);

    if (average > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%.2f\n", average);
    }

    /* FREE MEMORY */
    for (p = 0; username[p]; p++) {
        free(username[p]);
    }
    free(*username);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Error -

```
*** Error in `./task': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f55a2ee6998 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x791fb)[0x7f55a29731fb]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x8288a)[0x7f55a297c88a]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f55a29802bc]
./task[0x4007f9]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f55a291a401]
./task[0x40085a]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:31 433193010                          /home/cshome/h/hmead/242/lab07/task
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 00:31 433193010                          /home/cshome/h/hmead/242/lab07/task
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:31 433193010                          /home/cshome/h/hmead/242/lab07/task
7f559c000000-7f559c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f559c021000-7f55a0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f55a26e3000-7f55a26f9000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 100663402                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
7f55a26f9000-7f55a28f8000 ---p 00016000 08:06 100663402                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
7f55a28f8000-7f55a28f9000 r--p 00015000 08:06 100663402                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
7f55a28f9000-7f55a28fa000 rw-p 00016000 08:06 100663402                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
7f55a28fa000-7f55a2ab7000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 100806032                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so
7f55a2ab7000-7f55a2cb6000 ---p 001bd000 08:06 100806032                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so
7f55a2cb6000-7f55a2cba000 r--p 001bc000 08:06 100806032                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so
7f55a2cba000-7f55a2cbc000 rw-p 001c0000 08:06 100806032                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so
7f55a2cbc000-7f55a2cc0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f55a2cc0000-7f55a2ce5000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 100806025                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.24.so
7f55a2dbd000-7f55a2ec0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f55a2ee2000-7f55a2ee5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f55a2ee5000-7f55a2ee6000 r--p 00025000 08:06 100806025                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.24.so
7f55a2ee6000-7f55a2ee7000 rw-p 00026000 08:06 100806025                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.24.so
7f55a2ee7000-7f55a2ee8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc89617000-7ffc89638000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc89739000-7ffc8973b000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc8973b000-7ffc8973d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
/home/cshome/coursework/241/bin/checkprac1: line 44:  4467 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./$prog < ${indir}/${file} >| ${tmpfile}.stdout 2>| ${tmpfile}.stderr
```

Comment: `for (p = 0; username[p]; p++) {
        free(username[p]);
    }
    free(*username);` --> `for (p = 0; p < num_words; p++) {
        free(username[p]);
    }`

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialised the pointers to NULL

```
char *username[SIZE] = {0};
```

And you are double freeing the first element

```
for (p = 0; username[p]; p++) {
    free(username[p]);
}
// then get rid of this line.... 
// free(*username);
```

Comment: For my own understanding, could you please explain why it is necessary to initialize to NULL?

Comment: You're looping over the array of `username`s assuming it ends with a `NULL`, however, you leave garbage values at the end instead which you try to `free`.

Comment: This for loop is very strange. It does not check for upper bound

Comment: I found the for loop here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436669/how-to-free-an-array-of-char-pointer

Comment: @eZ_Harry This only works if you know that the last pointer is set to NULL, which does not seems to be your case

Comment: Is that not what this answer suggested I change?

Comment: This code could run into problems if all 100 words were entered; there wouldn't be a reliable null pointer within the bounds of the array.